# Stringの"[1,2]"という値を、int配列に変換する方法

Tags: java

Stringの"[1,2]"という値を、int配列に変換する方法をご教授下さい

Comment: 直接的な方法はなくて、自前でパースするしかないのかなと思います。

Comment: FYI: それなりに知名度のあるJSONライブラリ一覧 https://github.com/akullpp/awesome-java#json

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java8 の stream を使ってパースしてみました。

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class stringToIntArray {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    String str = "[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]";

    int[] arr = Arrays.stream(str.split("[, \\[\\]]"))
      .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
      .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
      .toArray();

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
  }
}

=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: とてもすっきりしていて、良いですね。ご回答ありがとう御座います。

Answer (score 8):

[JSON](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Object_Notation)形式の配列とみなせるのでJSONパーサが利用できると思います。

[jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind)を利用した例:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

...

        final String target = "[1,2]";

        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final int[] result = mapper.readValue(target, int[].class);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

結果:

```
[1, 2]
```

---

あるいは、数字列が非数字列で区切られているとみなせるのなら単に

```java
final String target = "[1,2]";
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\D+");
final int[] result = p.splitAsStream(target)
    .filter(str -> !str.isEmpty())
    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

でも良いかと思います。